# Pivoting 2 column in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I got result data from table B2BSALES like this

[image: TABLE B2BSALES]

What i can do just with unpivot just like this from this query

```
    SELECT [Date], [Desc], AREA,Value as TotalAmt 
FROM [dbo].[StagingSalesB2BINDOMA]
UNPIVOT
    (Value FOR AREA in
        (TOTAL, Bandung, CIREBON, BANJARMASIN, BATAM, BALI)
)AS unpvt;
```

[image: PIVOTB2BAREA]

just get column city as area

what i want is like this

[image]

how can i do it with query , can i use join before pivoting , thanks before

Comment: where is your sql query? You need to put it in your question

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to unpivot.  I recommend `apply` :

```
select t.date, t.[desc], v.area.v.amt
from t cross apply
     (values ('Total', total),
             ('Bandung', bandung),
             ('Cirebon', cirebon),
             . . . 
     ) as v(area, amt);
```